# How to Use "Yarn" From a Docker Container as if It Were Installed on the Host Machine

Tags: linux, docker, yarnpkg

I rely on Docker containers on local Linux machine as much as possible.

When working on Node projects I'm running Yarn like this:

```
docker run --rm --user=node -v "$(pwd)"/:/app -w=/app -it node:14.21.1-alpine yarn install
```

I would like to run it as if it were installed on host machine, to avoid lengthy command - e.g.
`yarn install` - with no local installation of `yarn`.

Comment: Q: Wouldn't it make more sense to create a Docker image with your dependencies already pre-installed?

Comment: @paulsm4 - I don't understand the question, could you elaborate please?

Comment: This is more general question, not only for `yarn`. It can be any other command: e.g. `python` (maybe some special version).

Comment: You should be able to `apt-get install` Node and Yarn with a single command; there's no particular reason to use Docker here.  (If you're just trying to use Docker as a package manager to work on host code, use an actual package manager instead.)

Comment: @DavidMaze I believe you didn't understand the request because someone changed my original question. I want to be able to use docker title says all, actually)

Comment: I in fact don't understand why you want to run every command inside an isolated container, but then go to extra lengths to disable the isolation feature.  Why is "run it in Docker but pretend it's on the host" better than "run it on the host", especially when installation is very easy?

Comment: @DavidMaze I want to avoid installation on host machine. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Idea

Create executable bash script in `~/bin` called yarn

##### Steps

###### Create ~/bin folder if necessary

`mkdir ~/bin`

###### Create/Edit yarn script file

`nano ~/bin/yarn`
and paste the following, then save:

```
#!/bin/bash
docker run --rm --user=node -v "$(pwd)"/:/app -w=/app node:14.21.1-alpine yarn "$@"
```

##### Make it executable

`chmod +x ~/bin/yarn`

##### Explanation

This way I can easily change/use any docker version of yarn and avoid pollution of my host machine (laptop).